# Regex pattern match a filename

Tags: c#, regex

I have a file name which must look like this:

```
A123456_B123456_v1.10_File Name.xml
```

I tried to create a regex pattern which should validate if the file name is a match.

The pattern is:

```
Regex regex = new Regex("A(\\d{6})_B(\\d{6})_v(\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,2})_(\\*?).xml");
```

It is not working.

Can you fix this for me, please?

**Working example**

```
string fileName = "A545656_B958432_v12.8_Upload 1.xml";

Regex.IsMatch("A(\\d{6})_B(\\d{6})_v(\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,2})_(.*?)\\.xml", fileName)
```

Comment: How about replacing `(\\*?)` with `.*?` ? You are currently matching a literal `*` here, which is not what you want (I guess)

Comment: http://www.regexper.com/ - this is the best thing ever.

Comment: You'll want to escape that last period as well - `\.xml`

Comment: This works but its gigantic lol :- string Reg = "^[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{6}[_]{1}[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{6}[_]{1}[v]{1}[1]{1}[.]{1}[1]{1}[0]{1}[_]*"

Comment: @Derek Thanks, but i need something like i have above. I am close, but i can't make it working

Comment: @RaraituL I found your mistake and edited my answer accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this Regex should work:

```
"A\\d{6}_B\\d{6}_v\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,2}_.*?\\.xml"
```

The round brackets are not necessary (though you can leave them as they are), the `(\\*?)` part is wrong, since it matches `A123456_B123456_v1.10_*` or `A123456_B123456_v1.10_`, but not `A123456_B123456_v1.10_File Name`, and `.xml` should be `\\.xml` instead, since you want a literal `.` to match, and not just any character.

The version with round brackets

```
"A(\\d{6})_B(\\d{6})_v(\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,2})_(.*?)\\.xml"
```

is needed only if you want to retrieve whatever was matched inside them.

**EDIT:**

The reason your Regex is not working, is because you're using `Regex.IsMatch` wrong. According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sdx2bds0.aspx), it's Regex.IsMatch(input, pattern)

```
Regex.IsMatch("A(\\d{6})_B(\\d{6})_v(\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,2})_(.*?)\\.xml", fileName) // instead of this
Regex.IsMatch(fileName, "A(\\d{6})_B(\\d{6})_v(\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,2})_(.*?)\\.xml") // do this instead
```

and since you're doing

```
Regex regex = new Regex("A(\\d{6})_B(\\d{6})_v(\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,2})_(.*?)\\.xml");
```

why don't you use it?

```
if (regex.IsMatch(fileName))
    // do stuff
```

**EDIT 2:**

Instead of using double-escaping, you can make your Regex easier to read by using the verbatim character `@`

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"A(\d{6})_B(\d{6})_v(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,2})_(.*?)\.xml");
```

Comment: Stupid me! I haven't realized this at all! I was testing it in the debugger, and i didn't wanted to compile the project every time i made a change on regex

Comment: You can get rid of all that double-escaping by just using a verbatim string literal.

Comment: @Јοеу true, I'll update my answer to mention that possibility

Answer (score 0):

Theres a cleaner way of doing it than this, but it will work.

```
private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        string Reg = "^[A]{1}[0-9]{6}[_]{1}[B]{1}[0-9]{6}[_]{1}[v]{1}[1]{1}[.]{1}[1]{1}[0]{1}[_]*";

        if (Regex.IsMatch(textBox1.Text, Reg))
        {
            textBox1.BackColor = Color.Green;
            textBox1.ForeColor = Color.White;
        }
        else
        {
            textBox1.BackColor = Color.White;
            textBox1.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't checks to see if it ends with .xml at end. I know i can check that separately, but i would prefer to do it here