# Require a Regular Expression to valid FileName?

Tags: c#, regex

I require a regular Expression to validate **FileName** in C# that ignores everything except all upper/lower alpha chars, numbers, backslash, underscore, period, dash, etc.  "*" and "?" for wildcards. I want to use that in `RegEx.IsMatch(fileName,expression)`

Comment: [something like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15157428/regex-pattern-match-a-filename)

Comment: Be aware that invalid filenames exist that are made up entirely of valid characters, like `NUL` or `COM1` etc...

Comment: You really should at least give learning regular expressions a go. It is extremely easy when you start at the beginning.

Comment: @Ravi And what's wrong with it? You should have an idea how an expression for what you want could look like so try create one your self.